# Basic Number Theory - Combinatorics Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

```
I am out for dinner with six people. The restaurant menu is divided into two 
groups: A and B, with six items in each group. We can select seven items in 
all, but must select at least two items from each of groups A and B. How many 
distinct dinner orders can we make?
```

[A1,A2,B1,B2] + [three random meals]

Maybe 6*5 *6*5 (6+6-4) C 3 ??

I created a Python program to solve this problem and I get 1068 but I am not sure how to do this mathematically. [The program was pretty hacked up, (don't judge me)]

```
a=map(lambda x: "a"+str(x),range(6))
b=map(lambda x: "b"+str(x),range(6))

from random import choice

store = set()
ww=1
while True:

    a=map(lambda x: "a"+str(x),range(6))
    b=map(lambda x: "b"+str(x),range(6))

    p = choice(a)
    a.remove(p)

    z= choice(a)
    a.remove(z)

    n = choice(a)
    a.remove(n)

    r= choice(a)
    a.remove(r)

    dual = a+b
    e = choice(dual)
    if e.startswith("a"):
        a.remove(e)
    else:
        b.remove(e)

    c = choice(a+b)
    if c.startswith("a"):
        a.remove(c)
    else:
        b.remove(c)

    f = choice(dual)
    dual.remove(f)

    base = [p,z,r,n]
    base.append( e )
    base.append( c )
    base.append( f )

    store.update([ ''.join(sorted(base)) ])

    ww+=1

    if ww==1000000:
        print len(list(store))
        break
```

This is pretty basic but any help would be great.

Comment: It makes a difference whether you *have* to choose 7 items, or on the other hand you may choose any number less or equal to 7 items.

Comment: So its actually a permutation not a combination

Comment: By the way, do you think my program generated the correct answer?

Comment: Still don't know if one must select total of 7 items, or may select fewer. Also it seems peculiar for one to use permutations in selecting the items, e.g. there's no real difference between picking a1,a3 from menu A versus picking a3,a1. You still wind up with the same overall collection of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order will be two lists of items, list A and list B. Usually for restaurant orders, it doesn't matter in what order the items are placed on a given list. However the two lists are distinct, likely because they have different items on them, maybe list A is the meal and list B is the dessert.

We'll assume order on each list doesn't matter and so one uses combinations, denoted $C(6,x)$ since for each list there are $6$ items to choose from. If the total number of items is 7, then the possibilities are $(a,b)=(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2)$ which means one computes
$$C(6,2)C(6,5)+C(6,3)C(6,4)+C(6,4)C(6,3)+C(6,5)C(6,2)\\ =90+300+300+90=780.$$
That would be the answer if one must select seven items and order doesn't matter on the lists. If order does matter just replace each $C(6,x)$ by $P(6,x)$ in the above, the result will be a much larger number.

Now if one may also order a total of 6, or 5, or 4 items, the count has to be increased by the possible ways: For 6 it can be $(2,4),(3,3),(4,2)$ and one gets $850$ for this, and for 5 it can be $(2,3),(3,2)$ for $600$ from this case, and finally for a total of 4 items (the minimal possible, if one is to select at least 2 from each list) there is only the $(2,2)$ case giving $225$.

So if one may select 7 or fewer than $7$ items, the total number of ways is $780+850+600+225=2455.$ (Again, if order matters on the two lists all the $C(6,x)$ must be replaced by $P(6,x)$ [permutations of 6 things $x$ at a time] and the result will be a much larger number.

Comment: I found it easier to take C(12,7)=792 and subtract the 2*C(6,1)=12 bad selections that are six of one and one of the other.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Yes that agrees with my more long-winded calculation provided OP means one must select 7 items and order on each list doesn't matter. It is a faster method, +1 on comment.